# Power BI AR Aging Buckets

Tags: powerbi

I am fairly new to Power BI and I'm building an accounts receivable aging report with 30, 60, 90, 120 buckets. I've got all the data and totals displaying correctly in a table, until I try to sort them into the buckets.

When the user enters an as-of date in a slicer, the aging balance should adjust accordingly (this works fine) and the balance should display in the appropriate bucket (I can't get this to work). I have a separate date table related to the charges table by the date of the charge, and I need to calculate the difference between the date of the charge and the date the user picks in the slicer, which is connected to my date table.

I've tried the selectedvalue() and max() functions on my date table, but since the slicer is for dates up to the chosen date and not for one single date, selectedvalue() doesn't work, and when I compare using max(), the chosen date updates to the max(charge_date) for the particular row. So, if I choose 3/31 in the slicer but the charge date is 12/31, the max date becomes the same as the charge date, and everything falls into the current bucket. I tried dissociating the date table, but then selectedvalue() won't display at all and max() gives me the very latest date in the date table regardless of what I choose. Then, all the balances immediately go to the 120 bucket.

In my mind, what I want to do is set a variable equal to the date choice in the slicer. Then I can adjust everything in the report based on that variable. But Power Bi doesn't work that way. Does anyone have any suggestions? I can post screenshots if needed once I'm logged into my work PC.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and desired results to the question?  In general you can write a measure that filters based on the max or min currently filtered Date.  You may need to take the red pill, and learn to use the mighty Calculate() function.  https://www.sqlbi.com/tv/dax-the-calculate-function/

Answer (score 0):

create a Calendar table without any relation to your Transaction Table.
Keep the Date slicer and Choose After

```
From 01 to 29 days = CALCULATE([Due Amount]
,FILTER('BDW Account Receivable',DATEDIFF(min(Calender[Date]),'BDW Account Receivable'[DueDate],DAY)>-30 
                              && DATEDIFF(min(Calender[Date]),'BDW Account Receivable'[DueDate],DAY)<0))
```